# Turn a company structure string into a table hierarchy

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to turn a company structure string into table hierarchy? 
`boss/manager_1/manager_2/manager_3/employee`

For example:

[image]

I've got this far but I'm stumped

```
WITH one AS (
             SELECT SPLIT(company_structure, '/') AS employees
             FROM t1 ),
two AS ( 
SELECT employees[1] as Level_1,
       employees[2] as Level_2,
       employees[3] as Level_3,
       employees[4] as Level_4
)
SELECT * FROM two
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays, what is `SPLIT()`?

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get parts of a delimited string.